# How to create regular expression dynamically setting jQuery validation pattern option

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a field with [jQuery.validate() plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) according to a regular expression. Ik need to validate if the answer looks like "999.12" of "468.47" or "123.45". So **[3 digits][dot][2 digits]**.

I'm dynamically setting the .validate()-option in an if-statement like so:

```
if (true) {

    $('#registerForm').validate().settings.rules.ssn.pattern = '[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}$';
}
else {

    $('#registerForm').validate().settings.rules.ssn.pattern = '';
}
```

When I enter .i.e. 123.45 it doesn't validate. Not even when I try

```
$('#registerForm').validate().element('#registerPassP');
```

in console.

I included all of these js-scripts:

- jquery.validate.min.js
- additional-methods.min.js
- pattern.js

Maybe something wrong with the regular expression?

Thanks all!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that `.` in your regex matches any character (except newline). It should be escaped to just match the dot - `\.`.

Comment: A thougt - in JS a regex is represented surrounded by `//` - have you tried `/^[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}$/` instead of `'[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}$'`?

Comment: a good thought, though I don't think he'd need the double escaped dot `\\.` should be `\.` ?

Comment: Just tried your suggestions (like `/^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}$/` and `/^[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}$/`). Sadly, no success...

Comment: So have you done any basic troubleshooting to determine if this is a problem with how you've setup jQuery Validate or with your regex pattern?

Comment: The validation works on all the other fields. When I type `$('#registerForm').validate().element('#registerPassP');` in Google Chrome's console it returns `false`. So I'm guessing it's a faulty Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Once `.validate()` is called and the plugin intialized, you [cannot dynamically change the rules](https://jsfiddle.net/cfat9v4/) without using [the `.rules()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

Something like this...

```
if (true) {
    $('[name="ssn"]').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
}
else {
    $('[name="ssn"]').rules('add', {
        required: false
    });
}
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/zp4vfxLb/](https://jsfiddle.net/zp4vfxLb/)**